# How to extract saved envelope values in Spatstat?

Tags: r, spatstat

I am new to both R & spatstat and am working with the inhomogeneous pair correlation function. My dataset consists of point values spread across several time intervals.

```
sp77.ppp = ppp(sp77.dat$Plot_X, sp77.dat$Plot_Y, window = window77, marks = sp77.dat$STATUS)

Dvall77 = envelope((Y=dv77.ppp[dv77.ppp$marks=='2']),fun=pcfinhom, r=seq(0,20,0.25), nsim=999,divisor = 'd', simulate=expression((rlabel(dv77.ppp)[rlabel(dv77.ppp)$marks=='1']),(rlabel(dv77.ppp)[rlabel(dv77.ppp)$marks=='2'])), savepatterns = T, savefuns = T).
```

I am trying to compare multiple pairwise comparisons (from different time periods) and need to create a function that will go through for every calculated envelope value, at each ‘r’ value, and find the min and max differences between the envelopes.

My question is: How do I find the saved envelope values? I know that the `savefuns = T` is saving all the simulated envelope values but I can’t find how to extract the values.  The summary (below) says that the values are stored. How do I call the values and extract them?

```
> print(Dvall77)

Pointwise critical envelopes for g[inhom](r)

and observed value for ‘(Y = dv77.ppp[dv77.ppp$marks == "2"])’

Edge correction: “iso”

Obtained from 999 evaluations of user-supplied expression

(All simulated function values are stored)

(All simulated point patterns are stored)

Alternative: two.sided

Significance level of pointwise Monte Carlo test: 2/1000 = 0.002

.......................................................................................
      Math.label               Description                                             
r     r                        distance argument r                                     
obs   {hat(g)[inhom]^{obs}}(r) observed value of g[inhom](r) for data pattern          
mmean {bar(g)[inhom]}(r)       sample mean of g[inhom](r) from simulations             
lo    {hat(g)[inhom]^{lo}}(r)  lower pointwise envelope of g[inhom](r) from simulations
hi    {hat(g)[inhom]^{hi}}(r)  upper pointwise envelope of g[inhom](r) from simulations
.......................................................................................
Default plot formula:  .~r
where “.” stands for ‘obs’, ‘mmean’, ‘hi’, ‘lo’
Columns ‘lo’ and ‘hi’ will be plotted as shading (by default)
Recommended range of argument r: [0, 20]
Available range of argument r: [0, 20]
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to access the values of the summary statistic (`ginhom`) for each of the randomly labelled patterns this is in principle documented in `help(envelope.ppp)`. Admittedly this is long and if you are new to both R and `spatstat` it is easy to get lost. The clue is in the `value` section of the help file. The result is a `data.frame` with the some additional classes (`envelope` and `fv`) and as the help file says:

> Additionally, if ‘savepatterns=TRUE’, the return value has an
>        attribute ‘"simpatterns"’ which is a list containing the ‘nsim’
>        simulated patterns. If ‘savefuns=TRUE’, the return value has an
>        attribute ‘"simfuns"’ which is an object of class ‘"fv"’
>        containing the summary functions computed for each of the ‘nsim’
>        simulated patterns.

Then of course you need to know how to access an attribute in R, which is done using `attr`:

```
funs <- attr(Dvall77, "simfuns")
```

Then `funs` is a `data.frame` (and `fv`-object) with all the function values for each randomly labelled pattern.

I can't really understand from your question whether you just need the values of the upper and lower curve defining the envelope? In that case you just access them like an ordinary `data.frame` (and there is no need to save all the individual function values in the envelope):

```
lo <- Dvall77$lo
hi <- Dvall77$hi
d <- hi - lo
```

More elegantly you can do:

```
d <- with(Dvall77, hi - lo)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Glad to help. Which part did you need? Please mark the answer as accepted then, so the question doesn't appear to be missing a proper answer.

Comment: The "funs <- attr(Dvall77, "simfuns")" is what I was looking for.